# Export database tables to sql files individually through SSH

Tags: mysql, sql, database, shell, ssh

As the question says, I have been trying to export each table of a database in individual .sql files. I know `mysqldump -u username -p DBName TableName > Export.sql` exports one specific table, but is there any way I can loop it and export all tables in individual files using SSH command?

Answer (score 1):

Find the tables in the database and iterate over it.

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p -N -D DATABASENAME -e 'show tables';
```

This will list the tables of a particular database. Do something like this to export all the tables of the database. (*Note: you need to remove the formatting charaters*)

```
for tab in `mysql -u USERNAME -p -N -D DATABASENAME -e 'show tables';` do
    mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASENAME $tab > ${tab}.sql
done
```

Comment: I actually want to export the tables in separate files, not to show them.

Comment: @TayeabaMila get the list of tables and  iterate over it and use mysqldump to export each table to separate file

Comment: Ah, I got it now. But it's throwing this error - `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `mysqldump` Any idea?

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `done`
But not it's showing this - mysql: [ERROR] mysql: option '-e' requires an argument
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
-bash: command substitution: line 1: `;'

`

Comment: watchout for the correct syntax `show tables`  surrounded by single quote. And the other two starting from `mysql` are backtick

Comment: copy pasted it, still same

Comment: `mysql -u USERNAME -p -N -D DATABASENAME -e 'show tables;'` what does this give?

Comment: Outputs the tables names.

Comment: `for tbl in ``mysql -u USERNAME -p -N -D DATABASENAME -e 'show tables;'``; do  echo "$tbl"; 
done`
Does this display the tables one by one ?

Comment: replace the above comment with a single backtick

Comment: There's a typo in the answer, the semicolon should be at the end, right before "do". Currently it's shoved between the apostrophe and backtick instead. I'd edit, but SO allows edits that change minimum 6+ characters for some ridiculous reason. So if op wants to try editing himself, there's that. (and thank you for the answer btw)